# PayPal IPN Live INVALID

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, sandbox, live

I have a listener.php and a normal form for my customer to pay with paypal.
i would identicate the payment so i want to use die IPN from paypal.

if i test the skript in the sandbox, i geht verified.
so i like to go live, so i change the address to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr.

if i test it live, i get everytime invalid.

my codes:

listener.php:

```html
<?php
error_reporting(e_all);
// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);
// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 0);
define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");
// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
 $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
 if (count($keyval) == 2)
  $myPost[$keyval[0]] = rawurldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
 $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
 $value = rawurlencode(stripslashes($value));
 $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
 $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
 $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
 $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
 return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
if(DEBUG == true) {
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}
// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');

$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
 {
 if(DEBUG == true) { 
  error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
 }
 curl_close($ch);
 exit;
} else {
  // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
  if(DEBUG == true) {
   error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
   error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
  }
  curl_close($ch);
}
// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
 // check whether the payment_status is Completed
 // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
 // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
 // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
 // process payment and mark item as paid.
 // assign posted variables to local variables
 //$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
 //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
 //$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
 //$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
 //$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
 //$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
 //$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
 //$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
 
 if(DEBUG == true) {
  error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
 }
 echo "ok";
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
 // log for manual investigation
 // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
 if(DEBUG == true) {
  error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
 }
 echo "nein";
} 
?>
```

and this is my form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Paypal Integration Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="TPHX8DJDCSX88">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Gutschein">Gutschein</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
 <option value="Option1">Option1 €0,01 EUR</option>
 <option value="Option2">Option2 €0,02 EUR</option>
 <option value="Option3">Option3 €0,03 EUR</option>
 <option value="Option4">Option4 €0,04 EUR</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/DE/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Jetzt einfach, schnell und sicher online bezahlen – mit PayPal.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

and the url: test.mohamadomeirat.de

what am I doing wrong?